# How do I count matching elements in an array?

Tags: liquid

I want to take an array and determine how many matching elements are within, then count them to determine which has the most of the same elements.

Example:

```
{% assign variable = "Cats|Dogs|Mice|Cats|Cats" | split:'|' %}

{% for v in variable %}

    // Da-da-da, magic happens here, count matching elements.

{% endfor %}

{{ mostCommon }} // Return the most common element in array being Cats.
```

Anyone done this before? I'm only a designer so I can't give a better example :)

Answer (score 3):

So I'm kind of hesitant to share this with you.. especially since you so clearly state you're "only" a designer (and probably don't want to get into technical details). But since you asked, here's my solution.

```
{% assign array = "Cats|Dogs|Mice|Cats|Cats|Mice|Mice" | split:'|' %}
{% capture mostCommonString %}{% include most-occurences array=array %}{% endcapture %}
{% assign mostCommon = mostCommonString | split: "|" %}
{{ mostCommon | join: ", " }}
```

Seems simple, right? Nope. You'll need the following code in your `_include` folder to power the `{% include %}`:

***_include/most-occurences***

```
{% assign array = include.array %}{% assign setString = "" %}{% for elem in array %}{% unless setString contains elem %}{% assign setString = setString | append: '|' | append: elem %}{% endunless %}{% endfor %}{% assign set = setString | remove_first: '|' | split: '|' %}{% for x in array %}{% assign removedElements = "" %}{% for elem in set %}{% if array contains elem %}{% capture newArray %}{% include array-remove array=array remove=elem %}{% endcapture %}{% assign array = newArray | split: "|" %}{% assign removedElements = removedElements | append: '|' | append: elem %}{% unless array contains elem %}{% capture newSet %}{% include array-remove array=set remove=elem %}{% endcapture %}{% assign set = newSet | split: "|" %}{% endunless %}{% endif %}{% endfor %}{% assign arraySize = array | size %}{% if arraySize == 0 %}{% break %}{% endif %}{% endfor %}{{ removedElements | remove_first: "|" }}
```

That's the main algorithm. Basically it:

1. Creates a set (only unique elements) out of the array.
2. Removes the set from the array.
3. If the array is empty, the last set we removed is the "most occurring set".
4. Go to 1.

And a tiny bit more:

***_include/array-remove***

```
{% assign ret = "" %}{% assign removed = "false" %}{% for elem in include.array %}{% if elem == include.remove and removed != "true" %}{% assign removed = "true" %}{% continue %}{% endif %}{% assign ret = ret | append: "|" | append: {{elem}} %}{% endfor %}{{ ret | remove_first: "|" }}
```

This is a tiny (relatively) algorithm that removes the first occurrence of a string from an array.

**Just a warning:** A lot of the algorithm relies on using `|` as a separator character. I'm working on [a version](https://github.com/Shadowen/liquid-functions) that uses `&`, which can be escaped with the `| escape` filter, but I don't forsee this to be a problem.

Unfortunately, all the spaces **must** be removed to help `{% capture %}` [not grab extra whitespaces](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/216).

Comment: Thank you Shadowen, I'll give it a try and see if I can get it to work!

Comment: Hey Shadowen, so when I try including this code it just tells me Error: Illegal Template Name. I tried this a few different ways, I copied both includes into their own files. Is this right?

`{% include 'include/array_remove' %}

{% assign array = 'Cats|Dogs|Mice|Cats|Cats|Mice|Mice' | split:'|' %}
{% capture mostCommonString %}{% include 'include/most_occurences' array=array %}{% endcapture %}
{% assign mostCommon = mostCommonString | split: '|' %}
{{ mostCommon | join: ", " }}`

Comment: Yes, they should be in their own files, as specified by the **bolded** filenames over each code segment in my answer. However, you don't need to add `include/` to the filename when `{% include %}`ing them. Jekyll knows to look in the `_include` folder. You should have three files total: `<the page>.html`, `most-occurences`, and `array-remove`. The latter two must be in the `_include` folder.

Comment: Yea that's the problem actually is I am not using Jekyll, but instead Rails 3 which runs on our own platform. I have to include it that way because it's how our system works. I got the error to be removed, but it's not returning anything. Perhaps our rails 3 doesn't support some of your features?

Comment: Does Rails 3 support including files, capturing data, etc? The function can be rewritten to all reside within a single file (just find all the parameters being passed around and get rid of them).

Comment: Hmm I tried all of that with no luck, just doesn't return anything for me. And I'm not skilled enough to figure out why :), thanks for trying though.

Comment: Liquid tends to silently fail when it crashes. It's very difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do in a single line

```
{% assign array = "Cats|Dogs|Mice|Cats|Cats|Mice|Mice|Dog" | split: '|' %}
{% assign grouped_elements = array | group_by: tag | sort: 'size' | reverse %}

{% assign highest_count = grouped_elements[0].size %}
{% for elem in grouped_elements %}
    {% if elem.size == highest_count %}
        {{ elem.name }} {{ elem.size }}
    {% else %}
        {% break %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

```
// output
Mice 3
Cats 3
```

Basically what we are doing is:

1. Convert string to an array
2. Group the array using `group_by`
3. Sort it by the `size` key
4. Reverse it so that we have a decreasing order
5. Get the size of the largest element occurance
6. For each element, compare its size with the largest element occurance
7. If they are equal, print the element and its size